# Mongodb documents export to excel or csv using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am extracting data from mongoDB collection (documents), How can I export them to excel or csv using pandas.

I am trying something like this: Suppose here mongo_docs has 1000 documents

```
for doc in mongo_docs:
  for key, val in doc.items():
    if key in fields:
        fields[key].append(val)
    else:
        fields[key] = [val]

data = pd.DataFrame(fields)
data.index.name = 'ID'
data.to_excel("output1.xlsx",header=True)
```

What is the best pythonics way and a faster approcah to export them to excel or csv file, As per my understanding my method is very time consuming.
Please also let me know if there is an another faster way to export except pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Got it : pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mongo_docs) :)

Question: Is there a way to delete one key from all the dict in a list? without using for loop.

My solution :

```
list(map(lambda d: d.pop('_id'), mongo_docs))
```

Better pythonic way than this?

Comment: If you don't want the `_id` field, filter it out at the projection stage, e.g. `db.mycollection.find({}, {'_id': 0})`